# Does linker include libc.so.6 in statically linked file?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker

When I link executable elf file dynamically it needs libc.so.6 shared library.
When I link executable elf file statically it doesn't need libc.so.6 shared library (it's not surprise).

Does it mean, that to assemble executable file with --static, linker includes libc.so.6 in it?
If not - what file does linker include? where can I search it?
As far as I know, linker includes static libraries in statically assembled file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you link as static, the linker will link all the needed object (`.o`) files from the static libraries (`.a`). For example, the following command lists the object files which are included in the libc6 library:

```
ar t /usr/lib/libc.a
```

(the exact path to libc.a of course differs from system to system)

So answer to your question is no, it will not link the *whole* libc6 library, but only the needed object files. And also, it doesn't do anything with `libc.so.6`, since this is only for dynamic linking. It works with the `libc.a` - static version of the library.

According to @janneb comment, the smallest unit to be linked is "section", so it might not even need to link the whole object files.

Comment: IIUC, sections are the smallest unit that can be linked, not object files. See e.g. the --gc-sections flag for GNU ld, and the -ffunction-sections and -fdata-sections options of gcc.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Where libc.a is stored? I can't find it even with help of "Find"

Comment: Try `find / -name "libc*.a"` to allow for a little different name. Are you able to link statically? If yes, it must be somewhere on your system.

Comment: I founded it with help of: sudo find / -name "libc*\.a". Thank you for support. :)

Comment: Great, @Lucky Man :-) What was the final path of your finding?

Comment: :) Attention, please! The final path is: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc.a. It also consists /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc_nonshared.a.
These files have a different size. What are the differences betweenn them?

Comment: I use something like `whereis libc` or `whereis libc.a` to locate a library in my system.

Answer (score 1):

The linker is the `ld` command. If you use that command, it does what you ask. Notice that GNU `ld` can accept [scripts](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html#SEC4)

However, most people are using the `gcc` command. This is a compiler from the [Gnu Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/) suite. Actually, the `gcc` command is just a driver program, which will run `cc1` (the proper C compiler), `as`, `ld` and [collect2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html) (which deals with initializations, etc. then invoke the linker).

To understand what exact command[s] `gcc` is running, pass it the `-v` program flag.

When you pass `-static` to `gcc` it will probably link with e.g. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a` or some other static form of the GNU Libc library.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can't find libc.a. What is the reason?

Comment: Did you try to run a `gcc -v -static -O helloworld.c -o helloworld` command to find out? Precise location of `libc.a` is system (i.e. distribution) specific.

Comment: statically linked file has crtbeginT.o, the file linked not statically has crtbegin.o - it is only difference between them in my case.